# What are first and second order phase changes?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

In my thermodynamics lecture course, the Ehrenfest equation for a second order phase transition was derived from considering the following graphs,
however there was little context in the section for what the graphs represent:

[image]

What do a first order and second order phase changes mean?

All I understand right now is that some substance is said to exhibit a first order phase change if when the transition occurs there is a discontinuity in $V$ or $S$? I am guessing that not all materials show this, and for those that don't but instead show discontinuities in second order partial derivatives of $G$, i.e have a discontinuity in $C_p$ or $\kappa_T $, are said to show a second order phase transition.

Can someone offer more context on the Ehrenfest equation for second order phase transitions and why this is useful/important to consider.

Comment: Your guess is correct - at what level does the discontinuity occur defines the order of the phase transition.

Comment: Sorry if this question does not make sense, but what do you mean by order of phase transition, can you give an example to illustrate. I understand how to distinguish the order from the graphs, but not what it means to call a phase transition second-order or first order.